# PouchDB - document structure if some fields will be updated more than others

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

I am writing a hybrid app for mobile that allows users to add reviews and ratings to a crowdsourced database of community resources. There are two categories of fields that differ in how frequently they're updated:

1) Each resources have some universal fields like name, civic address, zip code, description. These will be occasionally updated, and sometimes never updated. New resources can be added too.

2) Each resource also has some more frequently updated fields: new reviews and ratings can be added to a resource. And users do not have to be logged in to add new reviews. They can do it without authentication.

How do I structure my database(s)/documents so that I can securely allow people to add reviews to each resource, without authentication? I am considering storing the relatively static fields (resource name description) as one document, and the reviews/ratings as separate documents- is this a viable way? It seems like it would be more secure, since users wouldn't be able to modify the entire resource everytime they added new reviews and instead they would just be adding new documents. However, I'm not sure how it would impact performance.

(I watched Joan Touzet's talk on 10 common misconceptions and it was helpful. If anyone can point me to some more content/examples of how to structure my documents and databases in PouchDB to maximize simplicity/security, I'd really appreciate it!)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am considering storing the relatively static fields (resource name description) as one document, and the reviews/ratings as separate documents- is this a viable way?

Yes, absolutely!

> It seems like it would be more secure, since users wouldn't be able to modify the entire resource everytime they added new reviews and instead they would just be adding new documents.

And that's why. ;-)

With this design you also avoid conflicts, be it immediate `409` responses when multiple users or eventual conflicts once you move to multiple replicated databases. Also the documents get much simpler.

Keep in mind that you should copy over some basic info about the community resource into each review doc. It is totally possible that one user (an admin) deletes the "resource" doc, but the users don't want their ratings disappear in their timeline view. E.g. copy over the _id and url of the resource into each review.

> However, I'm not sure how it would impact performance.

CouchDB views would take longer to generate, replication would take longer, and the increased disk space might be a problem (but probably not on the server).

All in all, I can only recommend using separate documents for each review/rating. We took the same approach in a very similar domain (rating wines), and it worked great. We tried several other designs also, but to put each review into a separate doc simplified everything greatly.